# In codeigniter redirect to paypal after order placed ,submitting form from controller

Tags: codeigniter

I'm very new to codeigniter.my question is after submitting billing and shipping address how to i redirect to paypal.I mean is there any way to redirect/form submission from controller.Below is my place order function in controller

```
function place_order()
    {


        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('bill_first_name', 'First Name', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('bill_last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'trim|required');
            if ($this->form_validation->run())
            {
                $data_to_store = array(
                    'bill_first_name' => $this->input->post('bill_first_name'),
                    'bill_last_name' => $this->input->post('bill_last_name'),
                    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                    'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                    'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
                    'country' => $this->input->post('country'),
                    'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
                    'zip' => $this->input->post('zip'),
                    'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('sess_user_id'),
                    'session_id' => $this->session->userdata('session_id'),
                    'create_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                );
                $customer=$this->checkout_model->add_user('tbl_customer',$data_to_store);
                if($customer){
                    $data = array(
                    'customer_id' => $customer,
                    'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('sess_user_id'),
                    'session_id' => $this->session->userdata('session_id'),
                    'create_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                    );
                    $order=$this->checkout_model->add_user('tbl_order',$data);
                    if($order)
                    {

                            if ($cart = $this->cart->contents()):
                            foreach ($cart as $item):
                            $order_detail = array(
                            'order_id'      => $order,
                            'product_id'    => $item['id'],
                            'qty'       => $item['qty'],
                            'product_price' => $item['price'],
                            'sub_total' => $item['qty'] * $item['price']
                            );      

                            $cust_id = $this->checkout_model->add_user('tbl_order_details',$order_detail);
                            endforeach;
                            endif;

                    }

                    $this->cart->destroy();
                }

                    paypallllllllllllllllllllllll
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the bottom of [this page](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) of the manual, you can find the redirect()-function (using the URL-helper).

--- EDIT ---

Maybe something like this (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18645652/611450) answer):

```
$query_data = array(
    'business' => 'your-paypal-email-address',
    'cmd' => '_xclick',
    'item_name' => 'Order #' . $order,
    'amount' => '100.00', // update with your total price
    'shipping' => '10.00'
);
header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/websrc/?' . http_build_query($query_data));
```

Comment: Wietse,my problem is just save billing and shipping information how do i redirect to paypal

Comment: What's the problem: redirecting, saving information (from a from?) or even both? Please provide more information/code examples

Comment: i've posted code,now say that how do i redirect to paypal  from controller